# Tesseract training with serak trainer

Tags: tesseract, training-data

Actually I am trying to train tesseract with new font and I followed many steps but always ended with error so I decided to use jTessBoxEditor tiff/box generator which i load text file with standard text provided in some tutorials and chosen the font I need to train and 36 px font size then generated the box file for me all set then I went to serak trainer did the first 3 steps with no errors and gets completed successfully but when I click 4th button it gives me a msg that the normproto doesn't exist in project folder which driving me crazy and Idk If I am doing something wrong or what?

Would like to get help in this issue cuz it's driving me crazy.

Thanks max

Comment: I suggest you stay with jTessBoxEditor for the training part also -- the tool supports that -- instead of switching back and forth.

Comment: When I choose the box and hit run button it gives me error that eng.font_properties and eng.word_list and eng.frequent_word_list doesn't exist and I have no any idea how to get such files and why he need font properties if the purpose it that he create it to me while training tessera? !

Comment: Those files are required, according to [Tesseract Training guide](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/TrainingTesseract). word_list  files can be empty. See files under `samples` folder for examples.

Comment: And what about frequent_word_list can it be empty too? Also is there like tutorial link somewhere of how to use jTessboxeditor to train tesseract?

Comment: The tool follows and automates the training steps. If you're familiar with the training wiki, you'd have no problems.

Comment: Sure but manual doesn't mention how to use jTessboxEditor. So I was asking if a tutorial or guide that helps also u didn't mention if I can leave the frequent_word_list empty too or not

Comment: I tried adding the font_properties and words_list and still no luck. I am really so clueless what to do. I literally followed many ofthe tutorials on net with no success

Comment: Practice with the training source files provided under `samples` for language 'vie'.

Comment: I got it working lately thanks for all the help